# 'str' object is not callable, with print

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#python3

applicant = input("Enter the applicant's name: ")
interviewer = input("Enter the interviewer's name: ")
time = input("Enter the appointment time: ")
print(interviewer, applicant,  time)

always show error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How to deal with this?I am a beginner, this problem has made me crazy!

Comment: Did you earlier assign a variable by the name of `print`?

Comment: Is this the whole code? I see nothing wrong with it..

Comment: I still cant understand this error, but it has gone after i restart my mac.

Answer (score 6):

You have definitely used a variable named print and assigned a string to it before this code.

Did you try to print like this before this code?

`print = 'something,something'`

That's wrong. It basically makes print a variable and when you try to call the print function it instead calls this variable which has a string stored in it.

Solution:-
Well if you are writing code in an interpreter(which is most probably what you did), just open a new one and write the correct code only. if you have a .py file, then just edit out the `print = 'something'` part.
That's my guess.
All the best.

Comment: It's also possible that the op has redefined `input` somewhere in the script, the unedited question doesn't mention `print`

Comment: Thank you, your solution is helpful.